# German Keyboard {[] not working on Windows 10 Terminal and WSL

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In the windows 10 Terminal and Ubuntu console these key combinations dont work:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> = <kbd>{</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>alt</kbd>  + <kbd>8</kbd>  = <kbd>[</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>alt</kbd>  + <kbd>9</kbd>  = <kbd>]</kbd>

However, right alt (<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) works perfectly fine.

Everything works fine outside of these 2 command lines.
Is there a way to make the combination with ctrl work?